# How to add UglifyJS to a VueJS project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, plugins, uglifyjs

I need to add UglifyJS to a VueJS CLI 3 project. 
My vue.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
  publicPath: "./",
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
}
```

This is the error message I get after trying to run **npm run build**.

> Invalid options in vue.config.js: "optimization" is not allowed.
>   "plugins" is not allowed

I tried updating all packages and install the [webpack UglifyJS plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/).

```
package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "firebase": "^6.3.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-flickity": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.8.95",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {"no-console": "off"},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

How to add UglifyJS to the VueJS project?

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration, also did you really install uglifyjs plugin, it's not in your package.json

Comment: Yes, it's in my package.json: ` "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"`  This is my vue.config.js: `const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./",
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
  }` **I published a build but the code isn't minimized and __console.log__ is still displayed. Any ideas why?**

Comment: well did you follow vue cli document to add webpack plugin? to remove console.log you should use drop_console option

Comment: @ChrisLi yes I followed the docs. This is my config.vue.js with the plugin: `const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
module.exports = {
publicPath: "./",
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: isProd ? [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
          uglifyOptions: {
            compress: {
              drop_console: true
              warnings: false,
              drop_debugger: true
            },
          }
        })
      ] : []
    }
  }
}
` All console log output is still visible

Comment: Just added the optimizations property in my vue.config.js. Also getting `Invalid options in vue.config.js: "optimization" is not allowed.`. Ever found a hint?